# Unable to start kestrel in visual studio code in windows

Tags: .net, .net-core

**this is the issue I got while doing dotnet run**

crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
Unable to start Kestrel.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be
found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)         Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date. To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.      For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054. at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.DevServer.Commands.ServeCommand.Execute()
at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer.Program.Main(String[] args)

Answer (score 0):

create developer certificate by

```
dotnet dev-certs https
```

if you are on mac, trust the certificate

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

[further reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#trust-the-aspnet-core-https-development-certificate-on-windows-and-macos)

Answer (score 0):

**To mannually kill the kestrel server use this command to see the running process and it pid on the port 5000**

```
 sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P | grep :5000
```

then kill it with PID

```
 sudo kill -9 PID
```